# Why are there different results when assigning a value in a two-dimension array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

What is the difference between these two assignments? Why do they have different results?

```
arr3 = Array.new(2, Array.new(2, 0))
arr4 = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

arr3 == arr4  # => true
arr3 === arr4  # => true

arr3[0][0] = "/"
arr4[0][0] = "/"

arr3  # => [["/", 0], ["/", 0]]
arr4  # => [["/", 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `arr3` contains two identical objects, but `arr4` contains two different objects.

```
>> arr3 = Array.new(2, Array.new(2, 0))
=> [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>> arr3.map { |ary| ary.object_id }
=> [73703490, 73703490]
>> arr4 = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
=> [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>> arr4.map { |ary| ary.object_id }
=> [73670930, 73670920]
>>
```

Read [`new(size=0, default=nil)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new)

> ...In the first form, if no arguments are sent, the new array will be empty. When a size and an optional default are sent, an array is created with size copies of default. *Take notice that all elements will reference the same object **default***.

You created `arr3` using the form above, while creating `arr4` using the **literal constructor `[]`**.

> A new array can be created by [using the literal constructor `[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Creating+Arrays). Arrays can contain different types of objects.

If you want `Array::new` to behave as literal construct, then go with `new(size) {|index| block }` form.

```
>> arr3 = Array.new(2){ Array.new(2, 0) }
=> [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>> arr3.map { |ary| ary.object_id }
=> [73551460, 73551450]
>>
```

Comment: @sawa I'm done.. Corrections are welcome from you.. :)

Answer (score -2):

Two elements in `arr3` share the same `object_id`, so they will be changed together.

CODE:

```
arr3.each do |item|
  p item.object_id
end

arr4.each do |item|
  p item.object_id
end
```

But I still don't know why `Array.new` made this happen.

Comment: I suggest you make this a comment on @Arup's answer.

Comment: _I still don't know why `Array.new` make this happened._ -- Did you read the _doco_ link, I mentioned?

Comment: It's not a comment. I answered myself just the same time with @Arup's answer. I just saw this after I posted it.

Thank you for the answer and doc link.